# Can a positive linear functional on a $C^*$-algebra be extended to a positive linear functional on the unitization?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra, and $\ f:A \to \mathbb C$ a positive linear functional on $A$. Where $\tilde A$ is the unitization of $A$, is there a nice way to extend $f$ to a positive linear functional on $\tilde A$? Is this always possible?

Two approaches I took to this were to set $f(a + \lambda I) = f(a) + \lambda$ (I identified $a \in A$ with its counterpart in $\tilde A$), and $f(a + \lambda I) = f(a)$. I tried to show that $\|f\|_{\tilde A} = 1$ in the first approach, but I got stuck. The second thing that I tried was just computational:
$$
f((a + \lambda I)^*(a + \lambda I)) = f(a^*a + \bar\lambda a + \lambda a^*) + |\lambda|^2
$$
This seemed promising, but I'm not sure how to proceed. It may be my naivety thinking, but I seem to doubt there's any hope for the second approach.

Comment: A positive linear functional defined on a subalgebra can always be extended to the whole algebra, regardless of whether or not the whole algebra is the unitization.  This is proven, for example, in Theorem 3.3.8 of Murphy's book *C$^*$-Algebras and Operator Theory*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second approach cannot succeed, because $f(I)=0$; this guarantees that $f$ is not positive unless its zero (you have $|f(a)|\leq f(\|a\|\,I)=0$).

In your first approach, the right extension is
$$
f(a+\lambda)=f(a)+\lambda\,\|f\|,
$$
and then we may assume without loss of generality that $\|f\|=1$ (that is, $f$ is a state).

Now we can check positivity directly: if $b\in \bar A$ is positive, then $b=(a+\lambda)^*(a+\lambda)$ for some $a\in A$, $\lambda\in\mathbb C$. Then, using [Kadison's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Generalizations),
\begin{align}
f(b)&=f((a+\lambda)^*(a+\lambda))=f(a^*a+2\text{Re}\,\bar\lambda a+|\lambda|^2)\\ \ \\
&=f(a^*a)+2\text{Re}\,\bar\lambda f(a)+|\lambda|^2\\ \ \\
&\geq |f(a)|^2+2\text{Re}\,\bar\lambda f(a)+|\lambda|^2\\ \ \\
&=|f(a)+\lambda|^2\geq0.
\end{align}

Comment: Ah! Very nice. Thank you. Perhaps I need to spend some more time playing with the inequalities associated with plfs. Where can I find a proof of Kadison's inequality? Arveson?

Comment: You will find proofs in wherever they talk about completely positive maps. But, for a state, it is simply Cauchy-Schwarz: if $\{b_j\}$ is an approximation of the unity, then $$|f(a)|^2=\lim_j|f(b_j^*a)|^2,$$ and $$|f(b_j^*a)|^2\leq f(a^*a) f(b_j^*b_j)\leq f(a^*a)\,\|b_j\|^2\leq f(a^*a).$$

Comment: Nice answer. For other readers: Note also that any positive extension is of the form $f(a + \lambda) = f(a) + \lambda \| f \|$ and thus there is a unique positive extension that preserves the norm. In particular, a state extends uniquely to a state on the unitisation.