# Technical lemma about state space of a $C^*$-algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Consider the following proof from the book "$C^*$-algebras and finite-dimensional approximations":

[image]

Why does this proof work in the non-unital case? (see the last line). Maybe we have
$$\|a + \lambda \| = \sup_{\varphi \in \mathcal{S}} \{|\varphi(a, \lambda)|\}$$
where the states $\varphi: A  \to \mathbb{C}$ have been extended (uniquely) to states on the unitization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The states of $A$ extend uniquely (as states) to the unitization. The extension is $\tilde\varphi(a+\lambda)=\varphi(a)+\lambda$. It [easy to check](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2541433/22857) that such extension is a state.

And you have an extension $\psi$ of $\varphi$ that is a state, then $\psi(1)=1$ (a positive functional always satisfies $\psi(1)=\|\psi\|$). That gives you
$$
\psi(a+\lambda)=\psi(a)+\psi(\lambda)=\varphi(a)+\lambda. 
$$

I don't see a way to go about the proof in an obvious way as Nate and Taka make it sound, but here is my take. Write $n=\|a\|$. Then, with $\tilde\varphi$ the unique extension of $\varphi$ to the unitization as a state,
\begin{align}
\|a+n\|&=\sup_{\|b\|\leq1}\|ab+nb\|
=\sup_{\|b\|\leq1}\sup_{\varphi\in S}|\varphi(ab+nb)|\\[0.3cm]
&=\sup_{\|b\|\leq1}\sup_{\varphi\in S}|\tilde\varphi((a+n)b)|\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\sup_{\|b\|\leq1}\sup_{\varphi\in S}\tilde\varphi(b^*b)^{1/2}\tilde\varphi((a+n)^2)^{1/2}\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\sup_{\varphi\in S}\tilde\varphi(\|a+n\|\,(a+n))^{1/2}\\[0.3cm]
&=\|a+n\|^{1/2}\,\sup_{\varphi\in S}\tilde\varphi(a+n)^{1/2}.
\end{align}
Cancelling and squaring we obtain
$$
\|a+n\|\leq\sup_{\varphi\in S}\tilde\varphi(a+n),
$$
which is the non-obvious inequality that is needed.

Comment: Sure, but how does this solve my problem? I still don't see how this finishes the proof in the non-unital case.

Comment: I included one more paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but it is still not clear to me why the proof goes through. Shouldn't we check that $\|a + \lambda 1 \| =  \sup_{\varphi}|\varphi(a + \lambda 1)|$ or do you think this not necessary?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Let me think about it.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: I posted an argument, take a look.

Comment: Sorry I missed your last reply. I think this works, but at the line with the first inequality is the square not a typo?

Comment: I don't think so. It's the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was past midnight when I answered :P

Comment: Hi, I didn't understand the following point in Martin's answer:  "The only state in the unitization $\tilde A$ of $A$ that does not come from a state in $A$ is the state $\alpha(a+\lambda)=\lambda$." Is this really true?

Comment: No, it isn't. Any contractive positive functional on $A$  extends to a state in the unitization, via the obvious formula. I'll check if my answer still stands.